# Is there any way to make Django's USStateField() to not have a pre-selected value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I use USStateField() from Django's localflavor in one of my  models:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
   state  = USStateField(blank=True)
```

Then I made a form from that class:

```
class MyClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = MyClass
```

When I display the form, the field "State" is a drop-down box with
"Alabama" pre-selected.

Is there any way to make the drop-down box to show no pre-selected
value at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue (though I'm not aware of a ticket - I'd double-check there's not a ticket for it, and if not, [file it](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/#id1)):

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms import USStateField

class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        ...

    YOUR_STATE_CHOICES = list(STATE_CHOICES)
    YOUR_STATE_CHOICES.insert(0, ('', '---------'))
    state = USStateField(widget=forms.Select(
            choices=YOUR_STATE_CHOICES))
```

Above code from [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg53497.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats the thing I was searching.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really like the idea of inserting ----- into the list manually. When the field is set to blank=True, the blank option should appear at the top of the picklist automatically. Plus, if your state field is on Profile and you're using django-profiles, then you end up in the position of having to modify a reusable app.

I find it easier and cleaner to just copy the STATE_CHOICES tuple from the  file contrib/localflavor/us/us_states.py into the constants.py in my project, and then in models.py:

```
import constants
state = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2, choices=constants.STATE_CHOICES)
```

The blank=True option then works as expected without having to monkeypatch the list.

Answer (score 3):

Just reporting that this is fixed!  Also note that [localflavor](https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/) is [now a third-party package](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/localflavor/) and after installing (e.g. `pip install django-localflavor`) it can be used like this:

```
from localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES
from localflavor.us.models import USStateField


class MyClass(models.Model):
    state = USStateField(choices=STATE_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
from localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES


STATE_CHOICES = (('', '---------'),) + STATE_CHOICES
```

Answer (score 1):

The following hack also seems to work in both django admin and forms defined in views:

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES
USStateField.choices = STATE_CHOICES
```

The thing here is that the forms.py definition in contrib/localflavor/us/forms.py has a USStateSelect widget that does define choices as STATE_CHOICES. However, the model in contrib/localflavor/us/models.py does not define these choices. This way, blank=True settings for the field do not result in a proper blank first entry in the Select, I found out looking at db/models/fields/**init**.py.

An alternative fix is to change contrib/localflavor/us/models.py and add a constructor like this:

```
class USStateField(Field): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from us_states import STATE_CHOICES
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 2)
        kwargs.setdefault('choices', STATE_CHOICES)
        super(USStateField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # etc. etc.
```